# Javascript ExtJS emptyText doesn't show on Ext.grid.Panel

Tags: javascript, extjs

The empty text in Ext 4.2 seems to not be displaying for Ext.grid.Panel

I can demonstrate by using the javascript editor here: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.grid.Panel

Just delete the `data` config for the store, and then add the `emptyText` config for the panel on the first example. It should look like this:

```
Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    storeId:'simpsonsStore',
    fields:['name', 'email', 'phone'],
    //No data here
    proxy: {
        type: 'memory',
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            root: 'items'
        }
    }
});

Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
    title: 'Simpsons',
    emptyText: 'Test Empty Text', //Add emptyText
    store: Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('simpsonsStore'),
    columns: [
        { text: 'Name',  dataIndex: 'name' },
        { text: 'Email', dataIndex: 'email', flex: 1 },
        { text: 'Phone', dataIndex: 'phone' }
    ],
    height: 200,
    width: 400,
    renderTo: Ext.getBody()
});
```

Note that the text *will* show up, once you click on `Name`, `Email`, or `Phone` - once the grid gets sorted.

Is this an Ext bug? How can I work around this to get emptyText to show up without having to sort the panel first?

Comment: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.view.AbstractView-cfg-deferEmptyText

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No it's a feature. The point is to not show the empty text while the grid is loading data because it is not yet known whether there is data or not.

The feature is not needed when the data is all local though, so just add the following to the grid config:

```js
viewConfig: {
    deferEmptyText: false
}
```